# Is this a valid sentence? "Should there be any issues need to be clarified, please contact me"

Tags: grammaticality

Is this a valid sentence?

> Should there be any issues need to be clarified, please contact me.

Comment: Try "Should there be any issues needing to be clarified, please contact me."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not quite.  It should either read:

> Should there be any issues **that** need to be clarified, please contact me.

or

> Should any issues need clarification, please contact me.

Comment: Or just _Should any issues need to be clarified, ..._.

Comment: I had something very close to that in the second sentence and changed it.  I believe I had what you have but left in *there be*, which made it wonky.

Comment: _There_-Insertion makes things wonky, all right.

Comment: As a very picky point: Are we talking about clarifying the issues? Or is the *issue* that the content needs clarification?  _Should there be any issues or if you need clarification, please contact me._